# WCF Service Passing TimeZoneInfo

Tags: vb.net, wcf, service

I have a Silverlight App that calls my WCF service to get a list of the Time zones from the server. All Time zones are retrieved in the function on the server but I need to know how to pass these back to Silverlight.

My call on the server is below but I think I need to somehow serialize the TimeZoneInfo as a Know Type before I can pass it back. This is the point where I am stuck.

Please can someone help on this?

```
Public Function GetTimezones() As ReadOnlyCollection(Of TimeZoneInfo) Implements ITimezoneService.GetTimezones

   Dim timeZones As ReadOnlyCollection(Of TimeZoneInfo) = TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones()

   Return timeZones

End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

See this http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wcf/thread/f164f185-ae18-4775-a2ff-a814813d262d for a list of known types to add to allow `TimeZoneInfo` to be serialized.

This will work for the full framework but I don't really recommended it, I would rather use either the ID, or the built-in string serialization as proposed in [c# TimeZoneInfo serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7704891/c-sharp-timezoneinfo-serialization).

On the contrary, the Silverlight framework has its own lightweight version of `TimeZoneInfo` and thus won't be able to deserialize the `TimeZoneInfo` serialized by the full framework (since it's not the same type definition).

You should also note that, by default security parameter Silverlight has only access to `UTC` and `Local` (Silverlight client running machine locale) TimeZoneInfo, and that to use other time zones, you need to run Silverlight with elevated privileges because timezone information is registry based. See [silverlight Time Zone converting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4618107/silverlight-time-zone-converting) and http://forums.silverlight.net/t/186363.aspx/1.

In the end some did rewrite whole or part of the TimeZoneInfo class in their own Silverlight application (we had to too). See http://forums.silverlight.net/t/165067.aspx/1.
Silverlight doesn't have yet support for more than local to UTC or UTC to local time zone conversion natively.

Comment: Agreed with Paciv.  Your GetTimezones() function should just return a list of string pairs containing the .Id and .DisplayName properties.  You can use that for your list.  When actually doing timezone conversion, do it all on the server side.